# Redefining key-value pair in referenced mapping

Tags: yaml

Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML has "sequencer protocols for Laser eye surgery" example which first defines mapping with anchor label &id001 and then refers to the label but redefines one key:

```
 - step: *id001
    spotSize: 2mm             # redefines just this key, refers rest from &id001
```

Is this a correct YAML document? Is it possible to override keys this way?
This example fails in YAML parsers I could find online.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "merge" instead of override the key.

```
- step:
   spotSize: 2mm
   << : *id001
```

In `PyYAML`, yaml parser will ignore duplicate keys.